# Monitoring via SSH cause max-file-descriptor notice

Tags: ssh, solaris-10, max-file-descriptors

We have Solaris 10 servers at our company and we are using an monitoring application which polls the servers via ssh.  Every time the polling is done we notice max-file-descriptor kern. notice on the server's syslog.
I tried to change the max fd limit via Solaris Projects (i added a project named user.[user credentials used for ssh polling]  and set the max-file-descriptor with basic priv at 2048) but i still get the same notice and it still mentions (256) as the value for max fd instead of 2048. 
How can i configure my server so that the polling stop causing fd notices?

Thank you

Comment: Hi - Can you post the output of 

> prctl -n process.max-file-descriptors $$

on the host you ssh into?

Comment: NAME    PRIVILEGE       VALUE    FLAG   ACTION                       RECIPIENT
process.max-file-descriptor
        basic           1.02K       -   deny                             25599
        privileged      65.5K       -   deny                                 -
        system          2.15G     max   deny                                 -

Comment: This is as the user you're running these commands as or as root?

Comment: This is as the user which is set for the ssh sessions.